# The "next" parameter, redirect, django.contrib.auth.login

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to redirect users to custom url `"/gallery/(username)/"` after successfully logging in.  It currently redirects to the default `"/account/profile/"` url  While I know what I can override the redirect url in my `settings.py`, my url is dynamic thus it will not work.

Documentation states that I need to use the `"next"` parameter and `context processors.`  I have the `{{next}}` in my template, but I'm confused on how to actually pass the `"/gallery/(username)"`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

p.s: I'm trying to steer away from writing my own login view.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I confess I usually use 2 redirects in order to get something like this to work.

First, Make your own `registration/login.html` page. You can copy-and-paste the html example in this section of the [authentication docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users) to make the process a little easier. Instead of using the dynamic `'{{ next }}` variable from the context, however, hardwire the value of next to go to a generic landing view of logged-in users

```
<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="/gallery/" />
```

Then, in the view that you map to the `/gallery/` URL, extract the User object from the request (since the user will now be logged in, especially if the gallery view is wrapped in a `@permission_required` or `@login_required` decorator. Use that view to redirect to the appropriate user-specific gallery page:

```
@login_required
def gallery(request):
    url = '/gallery/%s/' % request.user.username
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Comment: I would say this is one `redirect` not two, which runs in the gallery view. Nice.

Answer (score 45):

Django's login view `django.contrib.auth.views.login` accepts a dictionary named `extra_context`. The values in the dictionary are directly passed to the template. So you can use that to set the `next` parameter. Once that is done, you can set a hidden field with name `next` and value `{{ next }}` so that it gets rendered in the template.

Comment: @django-d This should solve your requirement as it did for mine

Comment: i tried this but it seemed to me that this would statically set next without the ability to override from within a referring view if needed. however, this greatly broadened my understanding of how django works and might be a simple and direct approach, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If you already have the custom template for login form you need to add the following inside your `<form>` tag:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}" />
```

BTW, you don't have to create your own login view. django.contrib.auth.views.login works fine. You only need to create a template for it (`registration/login.html`)

Comment: This is exactly how I have it set up, but where exactly do I assign the value for "next".  And how do I specify a dynamic value for "next".

Comment: I see now, you want a username in {{next}} and you don't know it before the form is submitted. In that case you have to create your own login view. Another option is to use a little of Javascript to fill the 'next' field right before the form is submitted.

Comment: Man, question not about what.

Comment: This worked for me. I just had to add the hidden input tag inside my form.

Answer (score 6):

being an newbie to django and stumbling over this somewhat older thread i found a differing solution for the problem of dynamically (=override a custom default only if needed) setting the next-param that i'd like to share (working fine with django 1.5, earlier versions untested):

just as django-d i wanted avoid repetition and a custom login-view, so i used the stock `django.contrib.auth.views.login`-view by adding the line of

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html',}, name='login'),
```

to my urls.py and within the login.html-templates form-element:

```
{% if not next or not next.strip %}
  {# avoid django.contrib.auth.views.login s default of /account/profile/ #}
  {% url 'afterlogindefaultview' as next %}
{% endif %}
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
```

which to my understanding follows the decoupling-practice of the url-configurations from the views.
so for views that should redirect to my apps login and afterwards head to a non-default view
i use

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('%s?next=%s' % (reverse('login'), reverse('mycustomnext')) )
```

from the view where i want to have the user to log in. i use this to get back to the view where i left off for logging the user in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a static redirect to `/loggedin/` and then associate the url to a view that makes the correct redirect.

Login takes an extra step but if you want to use django's view it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

create your own view for logging in, with it's own url, don't use the admin's one.
you can store the next page in the session, or pass it as a GET parameter to the login view
(i.e. /login?next=gallery) just don't forget to sanitize and validate that value before redirecting to it.

Comment: I really don't want to create a custom login view, but even if I did your example doesn't show how to pass the username. How Is "/login?next=gallery" supposed to automatically redirect to /gallery/username. Also where am I supposed to place "/login?next=gallery" within the URLconf or within the view using a regex?

Comment: the username is available in the session data.
the URLconf part maps '/login' to your view. the ?next=gallery will be available in your view in request.GET['next']