# Why second user login redirects me to /accounts/profile/ url in Django?

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-authentication, django-login

I am using Django built in view for user login:

```
url(r'^user/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'users/templates/login.html'}, name='user-login'),
```

After login when I goto user/login again I can login second time. I submit the form and getting:

> The current URL, accounts/profile/, didn't match any of these.

I haven't declare this url in `urls.py`.

What I am doing wrong? Why framework want to redirect to this url?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`django.contrib.auth.views.login` redirects you to `accounts/profile/` right after you log in.
You may want to set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` inside your `settings.py` file to anything you like..

Comment: This is correct, although it's weird it's coded to redirect somewhere that doesn't exist. Surely redirecting to '/' would be a more sensible default?

Comment: Worked great. Adding the text "LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = ('..')" to settings.py worked for me to redirect the user back to the default main page.

Comment: it says `This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times.`

Answer (score 8):

[Explained in doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url):

> (accounts/profile/ is ...) The URL where requests are redirected after login when the
>   contrib.auth.login view gets no next parameter.

Because you are yet authenticated your request is redirected to this url. To avoid redirect you should logout user before send it to `user/login`, create your custom login view or [append Next parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441436/the-next-parameter-redirect-django-contrib-auth-login).

Answer (score 3):

check your login.html

```
<form method="post" action=".">
    ~blah~
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/"><!-- login.html must send "next" parameter, and "next" parameter value is url that you want to redirect.  -->
    ~blah~
</form>
```

good luck~

Answer (score 1):

All of this did not work for me. I used a JavaScript solution:

In the login.html (where the social login buttons are) I put this script which stores next in local storage::

```
<script>
// Check for local storage
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    var h = window.location.href;
    if (h.indexOf("next") > 0){
        var tokens = h.split("=");
        var nextUrl = tokens[1];

        for(i = 2;i< tokens.length;i++){
            nextUrl += ("=" + tokens[i]);
        }
        localStorage.setItem("next",nextUrl);

    }
}
</script>
```

In the page where the users are being redirected to I used the following script to redirect:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Check for local storage
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            var nextUrl = localStorage.getItem("next");
            if (nextUrl.length > 0){
                localStorage.setItem("next","");
                window.location = nextUrl;
            }
    }
    else {
        // Sorry! No web storage support..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use the view build in django. and you are successfully logged in. django.contrib.auth.views.login which is the django view you used.

It has inside a parameter called LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL that automatically redirects you after logging in. and is by default configured with Default: '/ accounts / profile /'.

wich is The URL or named URL pattern where requests are redirected after login when the LoginView doesn’t get a next GET parameter. says  documentation

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

Try adding this to the html page form you use to login.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `'/accounts/login/'` is set to [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) which is the path redirected to after login.

So for example, you can set Django Admin home page to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in `settings.py` as shown below to redirect to it after login:

```py
# "settings.py"

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'admin:index'
```

Or:

```py
# "settings.py"

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/admin/'
```

Answer (score -1):

Two ways,  either you can use logout "LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL" or

just use the url which redirects to the view method which has @login_required decorator

example

for second login , after logout (below code is in logout.html)

```
<a href ="/">Login again </a>
```

In views.py

```
@login_required
def home(request):
  return HttpResponse("Welcome")
```