# Django Rest Framework 404 after browsable API login

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am following the [Tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions#tutorial-4-authentication-&-permissions) and everything else works fine. The only problem is that when I try to login using the Rest Framework browsable API, I get a 404 after the login:

```
Request URL:    http://localhost:7000/accounts/profile/
Using the URLconf defined in shelter.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^times/
    ^admin/
    ^api-auth/

The current URL, accounts/profile/, didn't match any of these.
```

Times is the name of the app. The API login is redirecting to accounts/profile, I haven't set that url up so of course the response is a 404. I'm probably missing a simple and obvious step.

Comment: add it to your shelter.urls or account.urls and then you'll get a different error!

Comment: The `include('rest_framework.urls'` already is in my shelter.urls, that is, the project-level urls.py ... I guess the only problem is that the url accounts/profile isn't there yet. I believe the tutorial should write about that. Anyway if I logout and then login again using the url with a next parameter: `http://localhost:7000/api-auth/login/?next=/times/api/day_list/` it obviously works fine.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13186794/924300